# Failed to insert data to geoserver layer with WFS-T

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I am trying to make a POST request to geoserver in order to Insert a new feature.
I am using the example provided by the Demo section of geoserver.

I have modified it as following:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:geonode="http://www.openplans.org/geonode"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <wfs:Insert>
   <geonode:bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel>
   <geonode:the_geom>
    <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
      <gml:lineStringMember>
        <gml:LineString>
          <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
            88.247354197,21.438097723 89.247354197,18.438097723
          </gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LineString>
      </gml:lineStringMember>
     </gml:MultiLineString>
    </geonode:the_geom>
   <geonode:TYPE>alley</geonode:TYPE>
  </geonode:bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel>
 </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

When trying to execute it I get a message:

```
 Feature type 'bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel' is not available:
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDITED**
I tried to make a DescribeFeature request as:

```
<DescribeFeatureType
  version="1.0.0"
  service="WFS"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <TypeName>geonode:bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel</TypeName>    
</DescribeFeatureType>
```

I did the request through the Demo section of geoserver. I get nothing back. Checking the Developer's tools, I see the request is pending.

**EDIT II**

I did the DescribeFeature request using PYTHON Requests and I get something meaningful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:geonode="http://www.geonode.org/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.geonode.org/">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrelType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
  <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiLineStringPropertyType"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OBJECTID" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LENGTH" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="POWERLIN_I" nillable="true" type="xsd:long"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LENSHPKM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="VOLTAGE" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GLOBALID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SHAPE_LEN" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:element name="bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="geonode:bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrelType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

When I tried to do the InsertFeature request using PYTHON Requests, I got this error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
 <ows:ExceptionText>Feature type 'bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel' is not available: </ows:ExceptionText>
 </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Can you add the describeFeature response for that feature type?

Comment: Thanks. I am out of office. I will do that by tomorrow morning!

Comment: @iant I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues in my requests.
The first one was related with the URL.
Initially I was using this URL:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs'
```

Including my_workspace name in the URL is necessary for this WFS-T Insert (according to [here](http://www.ceus-now.com/getting-transaction-support-enabled-in-wfs-on-geoserver-boundless-opengeosuite/)):

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/my_workspace/wfs'
```

The second issue was related with the namespace I have defined: geonode
In the end the xml I used looked like this:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
   <wfs:Insert>
    <bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel>
     <the_geom>
      <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
       <gml:lineStringMember>
        <gml:LineString>
         <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
         39.247354197,21.438097723 89.247354197,18.438097723
         </gml:coordinates>
       </gml:LineString>
     </gml:lineStringMember>
    </gml:MultiLineString>
   </the_geom>
  </bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel>
 </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

The rest of the request command (using PYTHON Requests lib) is straightforward:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

print requests.post(url, data=xmlstr, headers=headers, auth=('geoserver_user', 'geoserver_pass')).text
```

**The problem to solve now is how to pass non spatial data in the request. Meaning values of the attributes.**