# Make a WFS-T Insert request to geoserver and add non spatial values to the layer

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

My question is somehow related with my previous one [Failed to insert data to geoserver layer with WFS-T](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203054).
I use python and requests in order to create a new feature in a geoserver layer. I have managed to make a successful request and add the geometry of the feature to the layer.

Now I am trying to make the same post request but also to include other values of attributes that they exist in the layer.

What is the format in order to achieve something like this? As far as I see, the Demo page of geoserver doesn't provide an example like this.

@iant helped me figure this out. This is how my xml looks like:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <wfs:Insert>
   <bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel>
     <the_geom>
      <gml:MultiLineString srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
      <gml:lineStringMember>
       <gml:LineString>
        <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
        39.247354197,21.438097723 89.247354197,18.438097723
        </gml:coordinates>
      </gml:LineString>
     </gml:lineStringMember>
    </gml:MultiLineString>
   </the_geom>
   <CODE>5</CODE>
   <POWERLIN_I>1</POWERLIN_I>
   <OBJECTID>2</OBJECTID> 
   <GLOBALID>fd</GLOBALID> 
  </bgd_uti_transmissionline_nrel>
 </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

Comment: Not the most elegant solution but maybe using Wireshark to monitor a WFS-T update from QGIS and reverse engineer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to look for details like this is in the [standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs).

Inserting non spatial attributes is done in exactly the same way as adding spatial attributes. First check the schema of the feature type by using a `describeFeature` request, then construct a `Transaction` request with the attribute values **in the same order** as the schema requires.

Comment: Thanks @iant. This works. But is it really the case that I need to provide the parameters in the exact order they are described in the describeFeature request? What I am building will be automated and will add an overhead if I need to retrieve the order of the attributes.

Comment: That's how xml works I'm afraid.

Comment: if you want you can check my edited answer. I made it work and although I don't follow the order shown in the describeFeature, still the values are updated correctly! :)

Comment: I can confirm that the order of the attributes does not matter.

Comment: Only because the GeoServer developers are kind. There is no guarantee it will keep working or will work if the server changes to a stricter one.